# macOS Maps Blank Default View

Tags: macos, maps

When using macOS Maps (currently on Big Sur), the Default view is blank.   Satellite view works fine, but default view only shows blank space / grid.

Searching online, seems a few have run in to this before.  Some suggestions are installing CCCleaner and other junk software.  Others suggest clearing out everything in ~/Library/Caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache for Maps specifically can be cleared by deleting the following folder
~/Library/Caches/GeoServices

Removing this folder and restarting Maps should allow the map data to be downloaded and displayed again.