# macOS - Maps not loading

Tags: macos, big-sur, maps

I'm on macOS 11.6 and my Maps.app isn't loading anything -
[image]

I believe I have good Internet connection and the requests to map services aren't blocked.

I couldn't figure out what's wrong and don't how to debug the Maps app.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Zooming in / out on the map
- Restarting the app
- Rebooting

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: That’s weird. What have you tried so far, in addition to, I presume, restarting your Mac?

Comment: Would this help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/427940/359458

Comment: Thank you @Alper, I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: I had the same issue and this fixed it for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427941